# keep checkbox state after changing page

Tags: jquery, sessionstorage

I am using the following code which is keeping the checkbox state when the page refreshes but as soon as I move to another page I am losing the state of the check boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if (sessionStorage.getItem('checked-checkboxes') && $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('checked-checkboxes')).length !== 0)
{
    var arrCheckedCheckboxes = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('checked-checkboxes'));
    //Convert checked checkboxes array to comma seprated id
    $(arrCheckedCheckboxes.toString()).prop('checked', true);
}
$("#checkboxes input").change(function () {
    var arrCheckedCheckboxes = [];
    // Get all checked checkboxes
    $.each($("#checkboxes input:checked"), function () {
        arrCheckedCheckboxes.push("#" + $(this).attr('id'));
    });

    // Convert checked checkboxes array to JSON ans store it in session storage
    sessionStorage.setItem('checked-checkboxes', JSON.stringify(arrCheckedCheckboxes));
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` will not persist its data when you navigate away from the page. To do that, you need to use `localStorage`. They both have a similar interface, so you should just be able to swap `sessionStorage` for `localStorage` in your code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick reply. I have tried changing sessionStorage to localStorage and it is still saving checkbox state on refresh but not when I move to page 2. I am using the same code to move through a dynamic page with different checkboxes. It is forgetting the checkbox state because I am calling the same page? Have you any further suggestions?

Comment: So the checkboxes you want to save are on a different page?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The checkboxes are paginated and you can click between pages. I want to be able to select a  checkbox from page3? and also page 1?.

Comment: If you're asking "how to create a multipage form" your question is too broad to be a good fit for this site; I recommend you close it. Try following a few tutorials to find an approach you're happy with, then you can come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Ok Simon. Thank you for your advice and taking the time to look at my issue.